# getting users area automatically on pageload in php

Tags: php, json

Below is a PHP code that gets latitude and longitude from the userAddress variable. Is there a way of getting a person's address automatically without user intervention like on page load. I want to get users latitude and longitude from that. Please help

```
$userAddress = urlencode ("Malviya Nagar Jaipur");
$aAddressData = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$userAddress&sensor=false");
$aAddressDataDecode = json_decode($aAddressData);
$userLatitude = $aAddressDataDecode->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lat'};
$userLongitude = $aAddressDataDecode->{'results'}[0]->{'geometry'}->{'location'}->{'lng'};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modern browser's built in GPS API with getCurrentPosition()

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`

Comment: I know that's javascript. Is there a way of getting address in php

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get this information by using the browser geo information. But the user must have agreed to share this information before.

You can get more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

PHP is server-side, therefore you can not use it to get what you want.

[Edit]

You can use javascript to write a cookie with the necessary data, than you can read it in your PHP using $_COOKIE

Comment: var latitude,logitude;
 
 function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
   document.write("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
 }
 
 
 function showPosition(position) {
   var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
         var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
   
         //Pass longitude and latitude to php how?
 }